# Run Testng Java code from Command Promt issue

Tags: selenium, testng

I am trying to run A Java Testng code using Command prompt, but this is always resulting in error. Though I am able to run the program from eclipse. The issue is while doing the same from command prompt.

Below is the code:

```java
package com.runit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class willitwork {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test(testName="Test")
    public void raise(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "H:/Softwares/New folder/chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Suite xml looks like below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="src.com.runit.willitwork">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: Did you set the classpath?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: If you have set the classpath.  Try Maven then.

Comment: Please share the exact error as already mentioned above. Also try to clean your project and M2 directory and retry it should help.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Please post the exact line you use to launch it via the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that you could be pointing to your chromedriver instead of the actual testng.jar and xml file that you want to run.
Here is how you can launch it from CMD:

```
java -cp "C:\yourpath\testng.jar:C:\project\runit\willitwork.class" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```